# How do I center the login button vertically in the menu

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

How do I center the login button vertically in the menu? I have a menu and I want to move the login button to the right and center it vertically. I tried to do it but it was not complete.

[image]

```css
.topnav{
    max-width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:92px;
}
.logo-container-1{
    float: left;
}
.logo-container-2{
    padding: 15px 0px;
}
.logo-container-2 img{
    height:58px;
}
.nav-content-1{
    width: auto;
    height: 92px;
}
.nav-content-2{
    float: right;
}
.nav-content-3 a{
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 35px 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    position:relative;
}
.login-container-2{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f56f46;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 7px 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="topnav">
            <div class="logo-container-1">
                <div class="logo-container-2">
                    <a href="">
                        <img src="https://www.strunkmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/bigstock-Print-163213010.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-content-1">
                <div class="nav-content-2">
                    <div class="nav-content-3">
                        <a>News</a>
                        <a>Live Tests</a>
                        <a>Current Affairs</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="login-container-1">
                    <div class="login-container-2">
                        <a>Login / Sign Up</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `aaaaaaaaaaa` characters ?

Comment: @KenLee Probably StackOverflow was not letting him post the answer because it was "too much code" and not enough normal text. I've never seen something like this though lol

Answer (score 0):

You can use these codes.

```css
.topnav{
    display:flex;
    background:#ddd;
    max-width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 92px;
}

.logo-container-2{
    padding: 15px 0px;
    flex:50%;
    justify-content:left;
}

.logo-container-2 img{
    height:58px;
}

.nav-content-1{
    height: 92px;
    display:flex;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:15px;
}
.nav-content-2{
    display:inline-block;
}

.nav-content-3 {
  flex:50%;
  justify-content:right;
  align-items:center;
}
.nav-content-3 a{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 35px 8px;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    align-items:center;
}

.login-container-1 {
    align-items:center;
    vertical-align:right;
    display:flex;
}

.login-container-2{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f56f46;
    border-radius: 4px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 7px 30px;
}
```

```html
    <head>
        <title>Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="topnav">
                <div class="logo-container-1">
                    <div class="logo-container-2">
                        <a>
                            <img src="https://www.strunkmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/bigstock-Print-163213010.png">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-content-1">
                    <div class="nav-content-2">
                        <div class="nav-content-3">
                            <a>News</a>
                            <a>Live Tests</a>
                            <a>Current Affairs</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login-container-1">
                        <div class="login-container-2">
                            <a>Login / Sign Up</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
     </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, To How do I center the login button vertically in the menu

```css
.topnav{
    max-width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:92px;
}
.logo-container-1{
    float: left;
}
.logo-container-2{
    padding: 15px 0px;
}
.logo-container-2 img{
    height:58px;
}
.nav-content-1{
    width: auto;
    height: 92px;
}
.nav-content-2{
    float: right;
}
.nav-content-3 a{
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 35px 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    position:relative;
}
.login-container-2{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f56f46;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 7px 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="topnav">
            <div class="logo-container-1">
                <div class="logo-container-2">
                    <a href="">
                        <img src="https://www.strunkmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/bigstock-Print-163213010.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-content-1">
                <div class="nav-content-2">
                    <div class="nav-content-3">
                        <a>News</a>
                        <a>Live Tests</a>
                        <a>Current Affairs</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
             
            </div>
              
        </div>
        <center>
         <div class="login-container-1">
                    <div class="login-container-2">
                        <a>Login / Sign Up</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <center>
    </header>
</body>
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.